# jenkins biuld failure due to reason "package does not exist"

Tags: java, jenkins

I am working on java struts project.There is a common database connection class in  project "a"(say) while other three projects are now dependent on that project "a".So in order to implement this I included the common project "a" in the build path of all other projects in eclipse.It is working fine in eclipse.Now as I build the project in Jenkins am getting the following error

> path..../a.java:[15] error: package com.......package name does not
>   exist

What additional configuration am I supposed to give in this situation.? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are using maven style of building, you need to include the project in the pom.xml as well

Comment: Thanks for your reply.As I add the dependency in the pom.xml of  other dependent project the pom.xml of project "a" is giving the error " missing artifact " What should I do.

Comment: Can't help without context. Show lines that you have included